# Why html5 canvas circle x doent corresponding to the X i given

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

My problem is I try to paint circles in an X position of a canvas and always painted with a difference of more than 100px I give. I see no pattern in terms of pixel added. The position of X given is that I need regarding this painting canvas where I do not need 100px or more. Leave a basic code sample.

Style

```
.defaul_paint
 {
  margin:1px auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
  float:right;
  background:#394147;
  max-width:660px;
  width:660px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
 }
  .paint{
  margin:1px auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
  float:right;
  max-width:660px;
  height: 340px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  background:#394147;
 }
```

JavaScript

```
function paint(xx, yy, radio, begin, grades, booleanVar, context) {
    context.arc(xx, yy, radio, begin, (Math.PI * 2), booleanVar);
    circle = new Circle(xx, yy, radio);
    circles.push(circle);
}

function testing() {
    var canvas, ctx;
    canvas = $('.paint')[0];
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = '#FFF';
    ctx.beginPath();
    paint(47, 5, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true, ctx);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

HTML

```
<article class="defaul_paint">
     <canvas class='paint'>
</canvas>
</article ">
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use CSS to resize your canvas--this will cause your pixels to be stretched.

Instead, resize the canvas element itself.  This will add pixels to the canvas.

You don't show your  Circle "class" here's a example code:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/VkV9n/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
window.onload = function() {

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    function Circle(x,y,radius,fill){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.radius=radius;
        this.fill=fill;
    }
    Circle.prototype.draw=function(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0,Math.PI*2);
        ctx.closePath();
        if(ctx.fillStyle!=this.fill){ctx.fillStyle=this.fill;}
        ctx.fill();
    };

    var c1=new Circle(150,150,100,"skyblue");
    c1.draw();

}; // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```